Using Antlr4 to parse an fASM inclusion file (.inc), handle inclusion statements, and if it's possible with Antlr4 (handle it), if it's not (skip it)
I'm trying to use Antlr4 to parse through an inclusion file (.inc) written in the syntax of fASM. This file may or may not contain other include statements. Here is an example snippet of such a file containing inclusion statements:
include 'Directory_Entry\Export\Image_Export_Directory\Image_Export_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Import_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Resource_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Exception_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Security_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_BaseReloc_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Debug_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Copyright_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_GlobalPtr_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_TLS_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_LoadConfig_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_BoundImport_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_IAT_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_DelayImport_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_COMDescriptor_Directory.inc'
include 'Directory_Entry\Image_Unused_Directory.inc'

; Contains actual values
    struct PEHeader
        mMagic                          dd  ?   ; // PE\0\0 or 0x00004550
        mMachine                        dw  ?
        mNumberOfSections               dw  ?
        mTimeDateStamp                  dd  ?
        mPointerToSymbolTable           dd  ?
        mNumberOfSymbols                dd  ?
        mSizeOfOptionalHeader           dw  ?
        mCharacteristics                dw  ?
    ends

; Contains pointers to where those members would be
    struct ptrPEHeader
        ptrMagic                        dd  0
        ptrMachine                      dd  0
        ptrNumberOfSections             dd  0
        ptrTimeDateStamp                dd  0
        ptrPointerToSymbolTable         dd  0
        ptrNumberOfSymbols              dd  0
        ptrSizeOfOptionalHeader         dd  0
        ptrCharacteristics              dd  0
    ends

The problem is, I can't seem to get Antlr4 to handle the inclusion lines correctly, it kind've chokes on them. Unfortunately, I do not have the output from when I was trying to parse the entire file; I only have the output of a small test file I made. Here is the contents of that file:
include 'Directory_Entry\Export\Image_Export_Directory\Image_Export_Directory.inc'

variable0 equ 5
variable1 dw

struct TestStruct1
    var1 db 10
    var2 dw
    MyOtherStruct var3
ends

Most importantly, here's the contents of the grammar file I have so far:
grammar fASMtoCHeader;

//@lexer::header {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::header {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::listenerheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::baselistenerheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::visitorheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::basevisitorheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

// Lexer rules
STRUCT      : 'struct';
ENDS        : 'ends';
EQU             : 'equ';
INCLUDE         : 'include' ['"] [a-zA-Z0-9_-~]+'.'[iI][nN][cC]['"][\r\n]-> skip;
TYPE            : 'db' | 'dw' | 'dd' | 'dq';        // Define built-in types (byte, word, double word, quad word)
ID                  : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
NUMBER          : [0-9]+;
COMMENT         : ';' ~[\r\n]*;                 // Rule for comments
WS              : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;           // Ignore whitespace



// Parser rules
program     : (includeStatement | equStatement | declStatement | structDefinition)* EOF;

includeStatement
    : INCLUDE STRING
    ;

comment
    : COMMENT
    ;

equStatement
    : (ID EQU NUMBER)
    ;

declStatement
    : ID type ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( '?' )
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER )
    | ID type COMMENT
    | ID type
    | ID customType ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( '?' )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER )
    | ID customType COMMENT
    | ID customType
    ;


structDefinition
    : STRUCT ID structMember* ENDS
    ;

structMember
    : ID type ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( '?' )
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER )
    | ID type COMMENT
    | ID type
    | ID customType ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( '?' )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER )
    | ID customType COMMENT
    | ID customType
    ;

type
    : TYPE
    ;

customType
    : ID
    ;

I've tried many different variations of handling the strings... I've tried
STRING : '\'' ~[\r\n]* '\'';   // Based on rule for comments
I've tried breaking STRING up into SINGLEQUOTE string and DOUBLEQUOTE string, but the combination of the quotation marks (whether it's single or double) with the un-escaped \ inside of the strings as part of the file paths seem to really throw Antlr4 for a loop. Since I did not know Antlr grammar file syntax (not the BNF style of content but more about how what is separated into what (i.e. what makes a line a lexer rule, and what makes it a parser rule), the grammar was initially created by me using ChatGPT and over many many iterations. The relevant content out of one of the iterations containing the single / double quote rules was this:
includeStatement: 'include' (SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING | DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING) ;
SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: '\'' ('\\' . | ~[\\'])* '\'' ;
DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: '"' ('\\' . | ~[\\"])* '"' ;

It had me trying things like this too:
STRING      : '"' ( ~["\\\r\n] | '\\\\' | '\\"' )* '"' 
             | '\'' ( ~[\\'\r\n] | '\\\\' | '\\\'')* '\''; // Handle single and double quotes


includeStatement
    : INCLUDE STRING
    ;

To which, I would get errors like this:
line 6:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\E'
line 6:31 token recognition error at: '\'
line 6:26 missing STRING at 'xport'
line 6:54 token recognition error at: '\'
line 6:77 token recognition error at: '.'
line 6:55 mismatched input 'Image_Export_Directory' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 6:81 token recognition error at: ''\r'
line 7:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\I'
line 7:0 mismatched input 'include' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 7:47 token recognition error at: '.'
line 7:26 missing STRING at 'mage_Import_Directory'
line 7:51 token recognition error at: ''\r'
line 8:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\I'
line 8:0 mismatched input 'include' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 8:49 token recognition error at: '.'
line 8:26 missing STRING at 'mage_Resource_Directory'
line 8:53 token recognition error at: ''\r'
line 9:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\I'
line 9:0 mismatched input 'include' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 9:50 token recognition error at: '.'
line 9:26 missing STRING at 'mage_Exception_Directory'
line 9:54 token recognition error at: ''\r'
line 10:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\I'
line 10:0 mismatched input 'include' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 10:49 token recognition error at: '.'
line 10:26 missing STRING at 'mage_Security_Directory'
line 10:53 token recognition error at: ''\r'
line 11:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\I'
line 11:0 mismatched input 'include' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 11:50 token recognition error at: '.'
line 11:26 missing STRING at 'mage_BaseReloc_Directory'
line 11:54 token recognition error at: ''\r'
line 12:8 token recognition error at: ''Directory_Entry\I'
line 12:0 mismatched input 'include' expecting {'=', ';'}
line 12:46 token recognition error at: '.'
line 12:26 missing STRING at 'mage_Debug_Directory'
line 12:50 token recognition error at: ''\r'

Can anyone provide the necessary corrections to my grammar file so that, if possible, the include statements are handled (I can get at them in the C++ generated parser code that Antlr creates) or are at least skipped? Thanks!

First, please read what I wrote in the last day about how Antlr lexers work here. There are a lot of problems here though. (1) INCLUDE         : 'include' ['"] [a-zA-Z0-9_-~]+'.'[iI][nN][cC]['"][\r\n]-> skip; ..... includeStatement : INCLUDE STRING; You can never use a lexer symbol that doesn't generate a token. Here you have INCLUDE, but it's marked as skip, which means "do not generate a token". Always print out the tokens that the lexer recognizes.

(2) You are trying to lex the statement include 'Directory_Entry\Export\Image_Export_Directory\Image_Export_Directory.inc' in one token because the INCLUDE also includes a reg. exp. for the string. Removed that and removed the -> skip. That also takes care of a problem in a character range set, which the Tool warned you about, and which you should have fixed.

(3) the grammar was initially created by me using ChatGPT. I have a whole discussion on ChatGPT here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/discussions/4127. I started trying ChatGPT with Antlr only a month or two after v3 came out. Generally, ChatGPT does not work for Antlr4 questions. It outputs grammars that are essentially unusable except for the simplest of grammars. It's best to start from one of the grammars in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.

Nevermind, I eventually got it. I broke it down into tiny baby steps to figure out where Antlr4 was having an issue and solve that first before moving onto more of the inclusion statement... Now if only I could figure out why it segfaults on unions inside of structs (I'm guessing it's because to end a struct and a union in fASM are both done via the ends keyword, but I feel like scopes should be tracked via some sort of stack operation. I feel like that would be a separate question though. In any case, here's the corrected grammar file (with some other fix-ups I did) in case anyone was curious:
grammar fASMtoCHeader;

//@lexer::header {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::header {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::listenerheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::baselistenerheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::visitorheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

//@parser::basevisitorheader {
//  #include "/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
//}

// Lexer rules
STRUCT      : 'struct';
UNION       : 'union';
ENDS        : 'ends';
EQU             : 'equ';
SINGLEQUOTE : '\'';
DOUBLEQUOTE     : '"';
INCLUDEFILEPATH     : ([a-zA-Z0-9_-~\\]+'.inc');
// include statements would patternize to:
// <alphanumeric | valid directory filename symbols> .inc
// <alpha> <alphanumeric 
// INCLUDE      : 'include' [a-zA-Z0-9_-+~]+'.[iI][nN][cC]'[\r\n]-> skip;
// INCLUDE      : 'include' (['"] [a-zA-Z0-9_-~]+'.'[iI][nN][cC]['"])[\r\n]-> skip;
// INCLUDE      : 'include' (['"][a-zA-Z0-9_-~]+'.inc'['"])[\r\n]-> skip;
// INCLUDE      : 'include' (['"].+)[\r\n];
// INCLUDE      : 'include' .+[\r\n];
// INCLUDE      : 'include' .{1,1}([a-zA-Z0-9_-~])+.{1,1}[\r\n];
INCLUDE         : 'include';
DUP         : 'dup(' ([0-9]+) ')';
TYPE            : 'db' | 'dw' | 'dd' | 'dq';        // Define built-in types (byte, word, double word, quad word)
ID                  : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
NUMBER          : [0-9]+;
COMMENT         : ';' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;         // Rule for comments
WS              : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;           // Ignore whitespace



// Parser rules
program     : (COMMENT | includeStatement | equStatement | declStatement | structDefinition)* EOF;

//includeStatement
//    : INCLUDE STRING
//    ;

includeStatement
    : INCLUDE SINGLEQUOTE INCLUDEFILEPATH SINGLEQUOTE
    | INCLUDE DOUBLEQUOTE INCLUDEFILEPATH DOUBLEQUOTE
    ;

comment
    : COMMENT
    ;

equStatement
    : (ID EQU NUMBER)
    ;

declStatement
    : ID type ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( '?' )
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER )
    | ID type COMMENT
    | ID type
    | ID customType ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( '?' )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER )
    | ID customType COMMENT
    | ID customType
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) ( DUP ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) ( DUP )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) ( DUP ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) ( DUP )
    ;


structDefinition
    : STRUCT ID structMember* ENDS
    ;

structMember
    : ID type ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( '?' )
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER )
    | ID type COMMENT
    | ID type
    | ID customType ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( '?' )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER )
    | ID customType COMMENT
    | ID customType
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) ( DUP ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) ( DUP )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) ( DUP ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) ( DUP )
    | unionDefinition
    ;

// Unions inside of structs seem to cause Antlr's generated parser to crash!
unionDefinition
    : UNION unionMember* ENDUNION
    ;

unionMember
    : ID type ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( '?' )
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER )
    | ID type COMMENT
    | ID type
    | ID customType ( '?' ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( '?' )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER )
    | ID customType COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) ( DUP ) COMMENT
    | ID type ( NUMBER ) ( DUP )
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) ( DUP ) COMMENT
    | ID customType ( NUMBER ) ( DUP )
    | ID customType
    ;

type
    : TYPE
    ;

customType
    : ID
    ;

